# Build a HttpMethod POST request with array of object from dto

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, post, http-method

I need to send an array of object as request body to POST API which looks like below.

```
[{
 "k1": "v1",
 "k2": "v2",
 "k3": 1
  }]
```

my dto file looks like below

```
public class Request {

    @JsonProperty("k1")
    private String k1;

    @JsonProperty("k2")
    private String k2;

    @JsonProperty("k3")
    private int k3;

    //setters and getters

    //override toString
    public String toString() {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
        return gson.toJson(this);
    }

}
```

my client implementation looks like below

```
final HttpEntity<Request> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<Request>(requestBody, headers);

final ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(URI, HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity, String.class);
```

Now i need help to build `requestBody`

being a JS dev , i am fairly new to Java. so, please be kind. ThankYou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mentioned JSON

```
[{
 "k1": "v1",
 "k2": "v2",
 "k3": 1
  }]
```

is a list of `Request` Object. So this `requestBody` object must be like -

```java
List<Request> requestBody = //your logic to build this variable;
```

Change in `httpEntity` to accept this request body:

```java
final HttpEntity<List<Request>> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<List<Request>>(requestBody, headers);
```

UPDATED: Example to build requestBody variable:

```java
Request request1 = new Request("v1", "v2", 1);

List<Request> requestBody = new ArrayList<>();
requestBody.add(request1);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How do i build the variable is my question.

Comment: edited question for that if that's what you are looking for.

Comment: requestBody we need to build has to be an array of object like this [{
 "k1": "v1",
 "k2": "v2",
 "k3": 1
  }] how do we build this using the variables declared in dto file (using getter methods of these variables)

Comment: Yes. once you will pass it to POST call it will be pass as JSON you have in your question.

Comment: How do i convert the requestBody into a JSON string if i have to pass it as JSON string to the PATCH call request payload

Comment: this line `final ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(URI, HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity, String.class);` is already doing it.

Comment: i was able to log the reqBody and it looks like expected JSON array of object. ThankYou.